# Как вывести значения при наведении на точку Highcharts

Tags: r, highcharts

Когда наводишь на точку принадлежащую "Значения 1" - дата корректно выводится (рисунок 1)
[image: Значения 1. Выводятся корректно]
А если навести на точку, принадлежащую "Значения 2" - дата не выводится. (рисунок 2) 
[image: Значения 2. Выводятся без даты]
Как сделать, чтобы выводилась?

```
hc <- highchart() %>%
  hc_add_series( name = 'Значения 1',
                 data = df1,
                 hcaes(x= Date, y = Value),
                 type = 'line') %>%
  hc_add_series( name = 'Значения 2',
                 data = df2,
                 hcaes(x= Date, y = Value),
                 type = 'scatter') %>%
  hc_chart(zoomType = 'xy')%>%

  hc_xAxis(tickmarkPlacement = "on",
           type = 'datetime',
           labels = list(format= "{value:%d-%m-%Y}" )) %>%
  hc_tooltip(valueDecimals = 2,
             xDateFormat = "%d-%m-%Y",
             headerFormat = '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
             pointFormat = "Дата: <b>{point.key}</b><br>Толщина: <b>{point.y} [нм]</b>" )

hc
```

Пример данных `df1`:

```
      Date        Value
1   2017-11-20   539.62
2   2017-11-27   540.49
```

Пример данных `df2`:

```
      Date        Value
1   2017-11-20   542.5
2   2017-11-20   543  
3   2017-11-27   540
3   2017-11-27   544.1
```

Comment: `{point.key}` на `{point.x}` не пробовали менять?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`point.key` нужно заменить `point.x` как указали в комментарии к вопросу. `xDateFormat` не дал нужного эффекта, поэтому формат даты был добавлен непосредственно в описание формата тултипа. В итоге получилось так: `{point.x:%d-%m-%Y}`.

Рабочий вариант кода:

```
library(data.table)
library(highcharter)

df1 <- fread("
N      Date        Value
1   2017-11-20   539.62
2   2017-11-27   540.49  ")
df2 <- fread("
N      Date        Value
1   2017-11-20   542.5
2   2017-11-20   543  
3   2017-11-27   540
3   2017-11-27   544.1 ")

df1[, Date := as.Date(Date)]
df2[, Date := as.Date(Date)]

hc <- highchart() %>%
    hc_add_series( name = 'Значения 1',
                   data = df1,
                   hcaes(x= Date, y = Value),
                   type = 'scatter',
                   color = 'red') %>%
    hc_add_series( name = 'Значения 2',
                   data = df2,
                   hcaes(x= Date, y = Value),
                   type = 'scatter',
                   color = 'blue') %>%
    hc_chart(zoomType = 'xy')%>%
    hc_xAxis(tickmarkPlacement = "on",
             type = 'datetime',
             labels = list(format= "{value:%d-%m-%Y}" )) %>%
    hc_tooltip(valueDecimals = 2,
               xDateFormat = "%d-%m-%Y",
               headerFormat = '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
               pointFormat = "Дата: <b>{point.x:%d-%m-%Y}</b><br>Толщина: <b>{point.y} [нм]</b>" )
hc
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое, все заработало!